# Deletion style on custom cell in table view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have implemented my custom cell in this way:

```
@implementation StandardCellWithImage: UITableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Base-List"]];

    _checkbox = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 24, 24)];
    _checkbox.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:_checkbox];

    /*textField with image/file name*/
    _nameLabel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10, 180, 44)];
    [_nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueCE-Bold" size:18.0f]];
    [_nameLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    _nameLabel.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    _nameLabel.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [self addSubview:_nameLabel];
}
return self;
}
```

and i use this in tableView. The problem is than when i swap cell to delete, there appear only red minus on the left side but cell doesnt shift to right. It looks like on image below:

[image]

How can i fix this problem to shift my custom cell to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to just littel change in your code

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Base-List"]];

    _checkbox = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 24, 24)];
    _checkbox.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [self.contentView addSubview:_checkbox]];//also change here 

  //  [self addSubview:_checkbox];

    /*textField with image/file name*/
    _nameLabel = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 10, 180, 44)];
    [_nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [_nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeueCE-Bold" size:18.0f]];
    [_nameLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    _nameLabel.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    _nameLabel.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
  //  [self addSubview:_nameLabel];


//  i just did change at one line now test your code
    [self.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];

}
return self;
}
```

i do using  `[self.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];` and working fine like:-

my UITableIVew:-

[image]

While Editing:-

[image]

Comment: It really works great!, you have solved my problem, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Set `autoresizingMask` property to your `UITableViewCell Label`. Like

```
_nameLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to define which element in list should be shift!